# NSolve with Interpolation function

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, interpolation

I am trying to apply NSolve to an Interpolation function which I have evaluated before. For a function of 1 argument everything works out but as soon as I try to apply the procedure for a function of 2 arguments Mathematica throws an error message at me. Here is my code

```
t1 = ListInterpolation[Table[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 2, .1}, {y, 0, 2, .1}], {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}];

FindRoot[t1[x, x] == 1, {x, 1}]

NSolve[t1[x, x] == 1, x]
```

FindRoot works but for NSolve mathematica does not evaluate the interpolation function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

t1 = ListInterpolation[
   Table[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 2, .1}, {y, 0, 2, .1}],
   {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}];
```

For the case where both arguments are the same, define a single-argument function

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := t1[x, x]

NSolve[f[x] == 1, x]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is there a possibility to store the InterpolationFunction in a kind of true function and work directly with it?

Comment: Look at [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) or related fitting functions.